labels for JVectorMap in Angular
For anyone who uses JVectorMaps, I'm trying to learn some basics here. I want to slap labels (two-letter abbreviations) on a US map and can't figure this out. I've tried many variations.
Component is called usa-map.component
the html contains this:
<app-world-vector-map mapId="usa-map-markers" type="us_merc_en" [options]="usaMapConfig" height="600px" width="100%">
TS contains an object called usaMapConfig, and I presume the API has some feature called "stateName" or something, but all of google's examples are either complex functions using nebulous words or just don't work.
Thanks in advance!
Doug
I've tried to insert many variation into here. The best I have so far is coloring states and adding a detailed legend. Again, I'm trying to put 2-letter names on each state. Then eventually I'd like to add dynamic data for each state, but that's down the road!
usaMapConfig = {
    series: {
      regions: [{
        attribute: "fill",
        legend: {
          title: "2023 production",
        },
        scale: {
          myScaleOne: "#c79efd",
          myScaleTwo: "#ffc371",
          myScaleThree: "#08d191",
        },
        values :{
          "US-IL": "myScaleOne",
          "US-CA": "myScaleTwo",
          "US-TX": "myScaleThree"
        },
        regionLabelStyle: {
          initial: {
            fill: '#B90E32'
          },
          hover: {
            fill: 'black'
          }
        },
        regionStyle: {
          initial: {
            stroke: "#9599ad",
            fill: "blue"
          },
          hover: {
            cursor: 'pointer'
          }
        },
        labels: {
          regions: 
          [{
            values: this.seriesData,
            scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
            // "US-IL": "test"
            
          }],
}


